# Windows IOT Raspberry Pi File Load Exception

Tags: windows-10-iot-core

I have recently upgraded my Windows 10 machine to version 1709 and I have a problem debugging my app on my Raspberry pi.

The app is a background app and I get the following exception in the output window and the IBackgroundTask run method is never called.

**Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileLoadException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll**

This is all I get - no idea on how to look further into this as there is no information on what it could not load.

I have tracked it down to me creating a class (simple creating am empty class is enough to show the error)

```
AquariumControllerPiLibrary.ABC c = new AquariumControllerPiLibrary.ABC();
```

This class is defined in a separate Class Library assembly.

The class source code is

```
using System;

namespace AquariumControllerPiLibrary
{
    public class ABC
    {

    }
}
```

If I comment out the class the Run method executes and I can debug the application and I do not get the fileLoadException.

Any idea how I can find out what did not load?

The debug lines from the output window.

'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'c:\data\Programs\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1_1.1.25915.0_arm__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\AquariumControllerPIVS.Debug_ARM.CCROWE\AquariumControllerPi.winmd'. Symbols loaded.

'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\AquariumControllerPIVS.Debug_ARM.CCROWE\System.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'c:\data\Programs\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1_1.1.25915.0_arm__8wekyb3d8bbwe\mscorlib.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\AquariumControllerPIVS.Debug_ARM.CCROWE\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.

'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\AquariumControllerPIVS.Debug_ARM.CCROWE\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\AquariumControllerPIVS.Debug_ARM.CCROWE\System.Threading.Tasks.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 
'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\AquariumControllerPIVS.Debug_ARM.CCROWE\ABC.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\AquariumControllerPIVS.Debug_ARM.CCROWE\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileLoadException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll

Comment: There seems no AquariumControllerPiLibrary.dll loaded. Can you show a snapshot of your Solution Explorer?

Comment: Sorry I ended up deleting the project and starting again and it is working now. But it was referenced in the project.